# How can I get the next monday if the first day of a month is in the weekend?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display `1` every first day of the month.

I wrote a code that is executed every working day, and if the value `monthly` is equal to `1` then the users have to execute something.

So this is what I did :

```
case when @today = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @today), 0) then 1 else 0 end 'monthly';
```

But now, my problem is if the first day of the month is in a week-end, the users won't see the `1` and won't execute their task.

So what I want is to do a test like this : if the first day of this month is either saturday or sunday then return the next monday.

The user will execute their monthly task even though the first day was in the week-end.

But, I have no clue on how to do it with my SQL knowledge.

Comment: If you have a [calendar table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/) then this becomes quite trivial, it also allows you to cover further scenarios where the first Monday of the month is a public holiday.  If you don't have a calendar table, then you might want to consider creating one.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the first monday of any month.

```
declare @YourDate datetime = dateadd(month, -3, getdate())

select dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(day, 6 - datepart(day, @YourDate), @YourDate)), 0)
```